# The integral $I=t\int_{0}^{s/t}f(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx$ for $f$ continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Specifically, I am having trouble verifying that $I$ does not depend on $t$. I tried to do this by differentiating with respect to $t$, but I cannot see why this derivative should necessarily be zero:
$$
I(t)=t\int_{0}^{s/t}f(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}=\int_{0}^{s/t}f(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx+
t[\int_{0}^{s/t}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx-\frac{1}{t^2}f(2s)]\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}=\int_{0}^{s/t}f(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx+
t\int_{0}^{s/t}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s+tx)\,\mathrm dx-\frac{1}{t}f(2s)
$$ 
Assuming I did everything correctly, why should that be zero? Also, what does the partial
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s+tx)
$$
mean here since $f$ is a function dependent on only $x$? I also tried messing around by parts, since I did gain that $x$ term in the integrand from the chain rule differentiating wrt to $t$ but it was to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we can make the $u$-substitution $u:=s+tx \Rightarrow du = t dx$, which gives:

$I = \frac{1}{t} \int_s^{2s}tf(u) du =\int_s^{2s}f(u) du$, so the actual answer doesn't depend on $t$. We know it can't depend on $x$ because it's a dummy variable.

Differentiating isn't a bad idea, but in general it's a headache to keep track of differentiating bounds in integrals. This worked well because the answer is linear in the relevant variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make notation like $tx=y$, and as f is continuously dependent on x, it will also be continuously dependent on y.
You will get what you want. That is $I = \int_{0}^{s}f(s+y)dy$.

Comment: thank you, this was helpful. Just to clarify, this then gives that $\frac{dI}{dy}=0$ and we are done?

Comment: It seems to me, yes. You can say that $\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$. Meaning that if i take $t+dt$ ,than $I(t+dt)-I(t) = 0$.

Comment: @qbert $y$ is just a dummy variable. Did you mean $dI/dt?$

Comment: @zhw What I should have said is $\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{dI}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ using the chain rule on the dummy variable. Is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to differentiate wrt $y.$

Comment: No matter. You can say that it depends neither on $t$ , nor on $y$, if that is desirable. ;).

Comment: @kolobokish that's what I thought.

Comment: @zhw Why  does it not make sense to differentiate with respect to y? Because it is the variable of integration? Then don't we just undo the integration?